# Can I swap an eletrolytic 200v for 400v

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

Please help me guys, I do not have much experience.
I have a power supply with two electrolytic 200v 680uf, and one is damaged.

Can I swap one for 400v 82uf?

This helps with performance and lifetime?

Thanks

Comment: try 680uF or so with low  ESR

Comment: This is an archetypical question: if someone doesn't know by himself that he shall NEVER replace a 680uF with a 82uf, whatever the voltage, this person should never ever try to replace those caps. Why don't you buy a new 200V 680uF one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely put a higher-voltage capacitor in, but the capacitance must be the same (or possibly larger). In other words, you should be looking for a 680 µF, 200 V or higher replacement capacitor.

Of course, this means that the capacitor will likely be physically much larger than the original, which may cause problems in tight spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much. But it means that the 82uf will have less lifetime than the 680uf?

Comment: 82uf is different from 680uf - no relation to lifetime. The capacity (in Farad) need to stay the same for the circuit to function as-designed. The (tolerable) voltage can be higher.